# Why I have two same permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql, permissions

I added permissions to database users by a T-SQL stored procedure like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[tbl_BookSubCats] TO [LibraryMemberUser]
```

But now I have two permissions as the same, in ssms. See this screenshot:

[image]

And my Windows application doesn't indicate the permission and gets permission error.

Why this is happened and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/959f9307-0494-4883-9d17-fad684705864/grant-select-permission-on-a-table?forum=sqldatabaseengine) and follow the steps:

> right click on table and go to properties -> permissions tab -> click
>   Add -> browse the user to whom u want to give the permission -> click
>   ok -> now u will find various permissions which u can grant -> in tht
>   tick on select checkbox under grant column.